# ERROR Login failed for user '<User>'. after publishing the web

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, web

I am getting an error after publishing a web. it say "Login failed for user ''. it works fine for the process that is not connecting to database, but when executing a process that need to connect to database the error showed up. 
here is the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''

I already tried some suggestion from internet to solve it, but it still the same. here my web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=<Name of the server>;Initial Catalog=Booth_db;Integrated Security=True />
```

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"  />
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  <globalization culture="en-GB"/>
</system.web>
```

I also tried adding impersonate identity but it give me an error on that impersonate identity.
do you have any experience about this problem?

Thanks in advances.

Comment: The user logging in to SQL Server is the user from the App Pool, since you chose integrated security. Make sure the app pool user can log on to SQL Server or replace the app pool user with one who can.

Comment: I'm sorry, i still don't understand about app pool stuff. did you mean adding my username into app pool?

Comment: Look here: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: It's already solved. I just need to remove the integrated security = true, and add userID and password... 
Thank you all...

Answer (score 0):

'Login failed for user' thrown by sqlserver when you are trying to connect to database with a specific user which may not have rights or Password is wrong.
Please check for database user password or try to connect with 'sa' user